# Combine a Join/Subselect Query with a SUM MYSQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql

### First MYSQL query

```
-- selects the latest records by unique member_id
SELECT * FROM table t
JOIN (SELECT MAX( id ) AS id
FROM table
GROUP BY member_id) t2 ON t2.id = t.id
WHERE `t`.`timestamp` >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)
ORDER BY t.id DESC
LIMIT 10
```

### Second.

```
-- sums the item_qt column by unique member_id
SELECT SUM(item_qt) AS sum_item_qt FROM table t
WHERE `t`.`timestamp` >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)
GROUP BY member_id
ORDER BY t.id DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Is there a way to combine these two queries so that sum_item_qt is joined
on member_id's?

Comment: Are the id's in chronological order, so that the where clause of the first query may be moved into the subquery? If so, `SUM(item_qt)` and `MAX(id)` can be found using the same subquery.

Comment: @TerjeD. That seemed to work. You should answer this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this query should give you the answer you are looking for:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 t
INNER JOIN
(SELECT MAX(id) AS id, SUM(item_qt) AS sum_item_qt
 FROM table1
 WHERE timestamp >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)
 GROUP BY member_id) AS t2
ON t2.id = t.id
ORDER BY t.id DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  a.*, c.*
FROM    tableName a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT member_ID, max(ID) maxID
            FROM tableName
            GROUP BY member_ID
        ) b ON  a.member_ID = b.member_ID AND
                a.ID = b.ID
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  member_ID, SUM(item_qt) sum_item_qt 
            FROM    tableName
            WHERE   timestamp >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)
            GROUP BY member_id
        ) c ON  a.member_ID = c.member_ID
-- WHERE
-- ORDER BY
-- LIMIT
```

Comment: You're missing the SELECT [, ID ] on the first INNER JOIN, as you set a.ID = b. [ ID ] I think the join needs the where clause also. Is this the most efficient way to do this?